# Обращение к элементу по id без getElementById.

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Разбирал вот такой вод код: timelessname.com/sandbox/matrix.html

```
s=window.screen;
w=q.width=s.width;
h=q.height=s.height;
m=Math.random;
p=[];

<body style=margin:0 onload=""><canvas id=q>
```

Описано ли где ни будь в документации по JS, вот такое обращение к элементу по id:

```
w=q.width
```

Если кто знает дайте ссылку.

Comment: О боже, типичный программист -___-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[вот тут описано](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) , впрочем лучше все-таки getElementById в силу того, что разные браузеры по-разному задают это свойство.