# Более короткий вариант обращения к id

Tags: javascript, ajax

Изучая ajax нашел в сети один рабочий код:

```
var li = list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
li.innerHTML = phone.name;
```

Меня заинтересовало как был задан `id` `list` элемента `ul`.

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Я ранее никогда не видел подобных обращений к идентификаторам. Не подскажете ссылку где можно об этом подробнее узнать? Ведь повсюду куда не глянь видна другая структура: `getElementById`, как же так что более короткий и удобный вариант столь непопулярен?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, походу да, но с таким названием его не найдешь =)

Comment: 12-й год, что вы хотите :)

Comment: @Levelleor, уже был такой же вопрос, но посвежее.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/204513/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE-id-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-getelementbyid